# Unhandled exception at 0x003860EF in Chapter1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0038EE7C

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am writing a very simple test program to swap all characters in a string pointed by char*. However, I got a really strange exception from Visual C++.

My code will be pasted below and Chapter1 is the name of the project.

Thanks everyone in advance and please feel free to post below to ask for any further question.

Question2.h

```
#ifndef _QUESTION2_H_
#define _QUESTION2_H_

namespace Q2
{
    void swap(char *begin, char *end);

    void reverse(char *str);

    void run();
}

#endif
```

Question2.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Question2.h"

using namespace std;

namespace Q2
{
void swap(char *begin, char *end)
{
    char tmp = *begin;
    *begin = *end;
    *end = tmp;
}

void reverse(char *str)
{
    char *begin = str;
    char *end = str;

        while(*end != NULL)
        end++;
    end--;

        for(; begin < end; begin++, end--)
        swap(begin, end);
}

void run()
{
    char *str1 = "hello";

    reverse(str1);

    cout << str1 << endl;

    return;
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Question2.h"

int main()
{
    Q2::run();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry that I didn't put all the question online at first. The whole question is to "Implement a function void reverse(char* str) in C++ which reverses a null-terminated string". So I assume I need to use char* as an input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration:

```
char *str1 = "hello";
```

creates a pointer to a string literal (a constant). You cannot write to the buffer (which the swap function attempts to do), otherwise it results in undefined behavior. If you are really wanting to use C style strings, then you could declare it as:

```
char str1[] = "hello";
```

With that declaration, it creates storage on the stack and copies the null terminated string into that array; it is still a null-terminated string.

One other thing from a correctness standpoint:  The loop that finds the end of the string should compare against `'\0'` instead of NULL:

```
    while(*end != '\0')
```

Comment: Thx for your quick reply. I updated the question just now and please have a look.

Comment: @jiyi: I believe the suggestion (answer) I made still applies.  The rest of the logic appears correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot easier, safer and readable with `std::string`:

```
#include <string>

void swap(std::string& str, int index1, int index2) {

    char temp = str[index1];
    str[index1] = str[index2];
    str[index2] = temp;

}

void reverse(std::string& str) {

    for (int i = 0; i < str.size() / 2; i++)
        swap(str, i, str.size() - i - 1);

}
```

Comment: thx for your quick reply. I updated the question just now and please have a look.